# htaccess Redirect from subdomain to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, http-status-code-301

I'm re-working a site and I'm attempting to move a forum from a subdomain (board.example.com) to the primary domain where the path will be example.com/index.php/forums/

I've set up my htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php/forums/ [R=301,L]
```

which works, but for all of the content that's already been indexed by search engines, the new URLs show up with old references, like

example.com/index.php/forums/?p=1199&sid=4daeb5acf7983a0f8d56737c4812f474

Is there any way to clear up the bit that's getting appended to the end of the new URL?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your sid parameter is coming from...

The way I would probably try first (before resorting to mod_rewrite) would be:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName board.example.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/index.php/forums/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. The sid parameter is from whatever wackyness phpbb was appending to URLs. I probably didn't have the board set up 100% correctly and when Google indexed, it probably was assigned a sid.

I tried what you suggested, and it doesn't seem to work (it causes a 500 error.)

Comment: Just edited my response, adding the "/" after permanent -- but now that I see that the problem is the "sid=" stuff is stuck in search indicies, I can tell you that my answer won't work.

So back to mod_rewrite.  You could try capturing various things (including the sid part) and then reconstructing an sid-less URL.

Something like (very roughly, you *will* need to fix this):
RewriteRule ^(.*)sid=([^&]*)(.*) http://www.example.com/index.php/forum/$1$2